# Iterate over associative array and send a single mail over the contents

Tags: bash, mailx

Below is the snippet from my script which I'm currently working.

**AArr** is an associative array that holds the queue names and its corresponding values(integer values) and an basic iteration over it(for) gives the below output:

```
for i in "${!AArr[@]}"
 do
   echo "NUMBER COUNT ON $i' is : ${AArr[$i]}"
done

NUMBER COUNT ON queue.hxi.1 is:  123
NUMBER COUNT ON queue.rui.4 is:  12
NUMBER COUNT ON queue.hxi.5 is:  35
NUMBER COUNT ON queue.fer.5 is:  1000
NUMBER COUNT ON queue.dcer.2 is:  45
```

I wanted to iterate the Assocative array but send only one e-mail in above format instead of sending mail for every iteration's key.
I'm bit stumped on the logic to achieve that ? Any inputs would be really helpfull.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't just pipe the output of the `for` loop to the `mail` command. It could be very well possible that the command can read over from standard input via pipe. So all you need to do is

```
for entry in "${!AArr[@]}"; do
   printf "NUMBER COUNT ON %s is : %d\n" "$entry" "${AArr[$entry]}"
done | mail
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, infact I tried that, unfortunately syntax errors that I didnt pay attention to. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can push all values from array into a variable like:

```
for i in "${!AArr[@]}"
do
    VAL="$VAL \n NUMBER COUNT ON $i' is : ${AArr[$i]}" # concat each value of array with existing in VAL
done
echo -e "${VAL}" # use -e to enable interpretation of backslash escapes
```

Comment: Appreciate your input :) but im looking to make use of single associated array to send out an email :)

Comment: How I understood, you want to send all text from array to an email?